# Delphi cef3 cast_sender.js failed

Tags: delphi, youtube, chromium

Использую компонент CEF 3.2924.1570, при загрузке youtube видео в логах вижу ошибки в cast_sender.js

[скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Dn3.jpg)

В чём проблема и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Смотрите, используется ли cast_sender.js при обычном просмотре. Потом смотрим адрес cast_sender.js и пытаемся открыть его в компоненте CEF. Потом ставим сниффер и смотрим логи.

Answer (score 0):

> используется ли cast_sender.js при обычном просмотре

Вы имеете ввиду в обычном браузере Chrome? Если да, то используется, в браузере адрес - `chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/cast_sender.js`, в компненте `CEF` - `chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js`. При попытке открыть в компоненте оба адреса ничего не происходит.

Comment: судя по началу адреса chrome-extension:// этот адрес от какого-то расширения хрома, а вот и обсуждение вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814914/chrome-youtube-cast-sender-js-console-error в гугле ещё есть по этому вопросу.